# Взаимозаменяемые проблемы в задаче по созданию массива во время исполнения C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Отрабатываю задачки по теме динамических массивов. Сократил все максимально и тем не менее - Возникает одна из двух проблем. Либо мне не дают запустить из-за команды копирования, либо же если я предлагаю компилятору ошибку игнорировать, он меня повреждением памяти пугает. Хотя за пределы массива я не выхожу. Еще веселье в том, что программа будет работать, если я уберу delete[]. [image: default]

[image: default]
[image: default]

Comment: У нас принято выкладывать код и ошибки текстом, а не скриншотами

Comment: Может, все же не `strlen(tmp+1)`, а `strlen(tmp)+1`? :)

Comment: Простите, в таком случае - либо
Severity Code, Error C4996 - Project File Line Suppression State
'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. Tuts C:\Users\XE\source\repos\Tuts\Tuts.cpp 13 

Либо 
HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#166) at 0x00D1CAD0.
CRT detected that application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы очень *удачно* вводите строку из одного символа, после чего получаете ее длину, начиная с символа с индексом 1.

Эта длина закономерно равна 0, посчле чего вы пытаетесь выделить память длиной 0 байт, что является UB и приводит к падению.

Comment: Большое спасибо Вам и Harry! Углядел